# My program needs to access information (key/value) from my hosted server. What web architecture would be best for this?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, web-applications

My program needs to download object definitions (basically xml files, maybe binary files) on demand via the net. The program will request objects from my server during runtime. The only thing the program has to send the server is a string that identifies the object it needs (e.g. RedCubeIn3DSpace23). So a basic Key, Value system. My app also has to have some basic authentication mechanism to make sure only legitimate programs access my server’s info. Maybe send the license number and a password.
What is the best way to go about implementing this? I have 0 web knowledge so I'm not sure exactly what technologies I need. I have implemented socket programs in college so maybe that is what I need? Are there frameworks for this type of thing? There could be thousands of users/clients simultaneously; maybe more but I don’t know.
One super important requirement is that I need security to be flawless on the server side. That is, I can't have some hacker replacing object definitions with malicious one that clients download. That would be disastrous.

My first thoughts:

-Set up an ftp server and have each xml file will be named by the key value. Program logs in with its product_id and fixed password and just does downloads. If I use a good ftp server, that is pretty impervious to a hacker modifying definitions.  Drawback is that it's very non expandable nor flexible.

-RESTful type system. I just learned about this when searching stackoverflow. I can make categories of objects using URL but how do I do authentication and other actions. Might be hard to program but is this a better approach? Is there a prebuilt library for this?

-Sockets using Java/C#. Java/C# would protect me from overflow attacks and then it is just a matter of spawning a thread on each connection and setting up simple messaging protocol and file transfers.

-SOAP. Just learned about it while searching. Don't know much.

-EC2. I think it (and other?) cloud services add a db layer over it.

That's what I can come up with, what do you think given my requirements? I just need a little guidance.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP seems a better fit than ftp, since you only want to download stuff. That is, you would set up a web server (e.g. Apache), configure it for whatever authentication scheme you need, and have it serve that content.

SOAP is clearly overkill for this, and using raw sockets would be reinventing the wheel (i.e. a web server).

I'd do security on the socket level, using HTTPS. That way, the client will verify the identity of the server prior when establishing the connection, and nobody can intercept the password sent to the server. Again, a decent webserver will support this out-of-the-box, you just need to configure it properly.